# Using Mesa EGL with custom protobuf version

Tags: dependencies, compiling, 17.04, mesa, mir

I'm using a multi platform EGL application on Ubuntu and I can't compile it anymore after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04.

The problem is the app uses Protocol Buffers 2.6.1 internally and Mesa EGL (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libEGL.so`) depends on protobuf 3.0.0 (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.10`). Linking two different versions of the protobuf library doesn't work.

I can't update the application to use protobuf 3.0.0 because it doesn't support a required [feature](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/548).

From what I've seen, Mesa's protobuf dependency comes from Mir. I tried today's daily image of Ubuntu 17.10 hoping it replaced Mir with Wayland but the dependency is still there. Same for Kubuntu.

This used to work on Ubuntu 16.10 because the default protobuf library was 2.6.1. There's no robust way to downgrade to 16.10 (unless I reinstall from scratch, of course).

Currently, I'm trying to recompile Mesa with X11 instead of Mir, using `--with-egl-platforms=x11`. I'm not sure if that will work. Maybe I need to recompile Mir using protobuf 2.6.1 but I don't know what the side effects will be.

My question is: Is there an easier solution/alternative?

Also, is it normal for an essential library like Mir to impose a strict dependency on a specific version of protobuf? Why doesn't the default Mir package come with a statically linked protobuf that doesn't expose this dependency to clients that want to use Mir? I know Mir development is already discontinued (or it will be soon) but I'd still like to understand why they made this decision.

[Chrome had the same issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=700120) and their solution was to link two different protobuf libraries at the same time by appending the `cr_` prefix to all global symbols in the internal protobuf library. They also note that this change is a hack.

Comment: Did you solve this?